# notifyDataSetChanged() not working on custom RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I was trying to create a `recyclerView` that shows a list of current statusbar notifications . I have created a custom adapter (`NotiRecyclerAdapter`) that takes a `List` of `NotificationItemInformation`

```
public class NotificationItemInformation
{
  int iconId,noitId;
  String packageName;
  Drawable notiIcon;
}
```

I am using an SQLite DB to store all the notifications.
The `NotificationListenerService` writes and deletes from the DB whenever a notification is posted or removed.

I use a method called

```
public List<NotificationItemInformation> ReadNotilist (Context context);
```

( which is inside myDBHelper ) to read the contents of the DB to a `List` of `NotificationItemInformation` called `data` (which is global,public and static in my Main Activity ) .
then I use `adapter`  (which is also global,public and static in my Main Activity ) to take the `data` and set it to the `RecyclerView` inside the `onCreate` method of my `MainActivity`.

So far everything is working well. and i can see the `RecyclerView` populated with the current `StatusBar` notification.

The problem is that the list does not update (if a new notification comes) till i restart the activity . I tried calling...

```
MainActivity.data.clear();
MainActivity.data = dbh.ReadNotilist(this); // dbh is DBhelper object
MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

...inside `onNotificationPosted` (after the adding into DB) of my `NotificationListenerService` . But still the `RecyclerView` is not getting updated till I restart the activity.

Here is my `MainActivity` if you want to take a look.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper dbh;

    RecyclerView notificationIconRecyclerView;
    public static NotiRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    public static List<NotificationItemInformation> data = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbh = new DBHelper(this);
        db = dbh.getDb();
        notificationIconRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.notificationIconRecyclerView);
        data = dbh.ReadNotilist(this);
        adapter = new NotiRecyclerAdapter(this,data);
        notificationIconRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        notificationIconRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,true));
    }
}
```

Here is my custom Adapter for the `RecyclerView`

```
public class NotiRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotiRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<NotificationItemInformation> data = Collections.emptyList();

    NotiRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<NotificationItemInformation> data)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public void registerAdapterDataObserver(RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver observer)
    {
        super.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_recyclerview_item,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        NotificationItemInformation current = data.get(position);
        holder.recyclerItemIcon.setImageDrawable(current.notiIcon);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView recyclerItemIcon;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            recyclerItemIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notiRecyclerItemIcon);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm curious to see your adapter's constructor. I suspect you're creating a copy of the data list or something similar. In fact, the entire adapter code would be useful to see.

Comment: @BenP. Thanks for the help , I have added the entire adapter code in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not reset the reference to the data object. Instead try something like this:

```
MainActivity.data.clear();
MainActivity.data.addAll(dbh.ReadNotilist(this));
MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter's constructor, you write

```
this.data = data;
```

This assigns the `List<NotificationItemInformation>` passed to the constructor to your adapter's `data` field. Your adapter is constructed like this:

```
adapter = new NotiRecyclerAdapter(this,data);
```

This means that your `MainActivity.data` field and your `adapter.data` field are both referring to *the same* list.

Later you write:

```
MainActivity.data.clear();
MainActivity.data = dbh.ReadNotilist(this);
MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The first line clears `MainActivity.data` **and** `adapter.data` (remember, they're the same list due to the way the adapter was constructed). The second line assigns a new list to `MainActivity.data`, but does not affect `adapter.data` in any way. The third line notifies the adapter that the data set has changed (which it has; it has been cleared), but your adapter won't "see" the new info from `dbh.ReadNotilist()`.

AChez9's answer works because using `addAll()` instead of assignment (`=`) means that `MainActivity.data` and `adapter.data` are still pointing to the same `List`, so the adapter will "see" the new info.

This is why it is often correct to create *copies* of lists when you accept them from an outside source. In other words, your adapter's constructor might want to do this:

```
this.data = new ArrayList<>(data);
```

This will mean that it is "safe" from changes to the list passed to it (in this case, `MainActivity.data`). But this means you also need to expose a way for your activity to update your adapter correctly. I'd recommend a method like this:

```
public void updateData(List< NotificationItemInformation> data) {
    this.data = new ArrayList<>(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```